# Apple watch not playing download files

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I've downloaded a file, now I'm trying to play it back

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let the = (paths as String) + "/" + (df.destinationURL?.lastPathComponent)!
print(the)
let fileUrl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: the)

let asset = WKAudioFileAsset(url: fileUrl)
self.downloadProgress.setText(String(asset.duration))
let playerItem = WKAudioFilePlayerItem(asset: asset)

self.player = WKAudioFilePlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
print(self.player.description)
self.player.play()
```

No sound is played.

However, any playing music IS paused, asset.duration DOES return the correct duration for the file.

Despite this, no audio is played at all.

Using `self.presentMediaController()` DOES work (using the same file URL), however, this pauses when I leave the app.

Any ideas?